# StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location. Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404 Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, file-upload, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with uploading an image with Firebase.

I can select an image but it wasn't uploaded to the Firebase storage.
The permission is read and write true in Firebase. And I allow an anonymous login to Firebase.

Error:

```
 E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    Object does not exist at location.
                     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
                    The server has terminated the upload session
                    java.io.IOException: The server has terminated Upload session:
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzacP(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzacO(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                    StorageException has occurred.
                    Object does not exist at location.
                     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
                    The server has terminated the upload session
                    java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzacP(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzacO(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Upload code:

```
    package in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.NetworkPolicy;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;
import id.zelory.compressor.Compressor;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
    private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;


    //Android Layout

    private CircleImageView mDisplayImage;
    private TextView mName;
    private TextView mStatus;

    private Button mStatusBtn;
    private Button mImageBtn;


    private static final int GALLERY_PICK = 1;

    // Storage Firebase
    private StorageReference mImageStorage;

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        mDisplayImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.settings_image);
        mName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_name);
        mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_status);

        mStatusBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings_status_btn);
        mImageBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings_image_btn);

        mImageStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();



        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid);
        mUserDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                final String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                String thumb_image = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

                mName.setText(name);
                mStatus.setText(status);

                if(!image.equals("default")) {

                    //Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(mDisplayImage);

                    Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(mDisplayImage, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {

                            Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(mDisplayImage);

                        }
                    });

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        mStatusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String status_value = mStatus.getText().toString();

                Intent status_intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, StatusActivity.class);
                status_intent.putExtra("status_value", status_value);
                startActivity(status_intent);

            }
        });


        mImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "SELECT IMAGE"), GALLERY_PICK);



                CropImage.activity()
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .start(SettingsActivity.this);


            }
        });


    }
    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            Uri imageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .setMinCropWindowSize(500, 500)
                    .start(this);

            //Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, imageUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SettingsActivity.this);
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Uploading Image...");
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while we upload and process the image.");
                mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();


                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                File thumb_filePath = new File(resultUri.getPath());

                String current_user_id = mCurrentUser.getUid();


                Bitmap thumb_bitmap = new Compressor(this)
                        .setMaxWidth(200)
                        .setMaxHeight(200)
                        .setQuality(75)
                        .compressToBitmap(thumb_filePath);

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumb_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                final byte[] thumb_byte = baos.toByteArray();


                StorageReference filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child(current_user_id + ".jpg");
                final StorageReference thumb_filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child("thumbs").child(current_user_id + ".jpg");



                filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                            final String download_url = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            UploadTask uploadTask = thumb_filepath.putBytes(thumb_byte);
                            uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> thumb_task) {

                                    String thumb_downloadUrl = thumb_task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                                    if(thumb_task.isSuccessful()){

                                        Map update_hashMap = new HashMap();
                                        update_hashMap.put("image", download_url);
                                        update_hashMap.put("thumb_image", thumb_downloadUrl);

                                        mUserDatabase.updateChildren(update_hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Success Uploading.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                                }

                                            }
                                        });


                                    } else {

                                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error in uploading thumbnail.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                                    }


                                }
                            });



                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error in uploading.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                        }

                    }
                });



            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {

                Exception error = result.getError();

            }
        }


    }


    public static String random() {
        Random generator = new Random();
        StringBuilder randomStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int randomLength = generator.nextInt(20);
        char tempChar;
        for (int i = 0; i < randomLength; i++){
            tempChar = (char) (generator.nextInt(96) + 32);
            randomStringBuilder.append(tempChar);
        }
        return randomStringBuilder.toString();
    }


}
```

Android Manifest:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".LapitChat"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".StartActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".StatusActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".SettingsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UsersActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat_TARGET_NOTIFICATION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ChatActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build Gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

APP Gradle:

```
 buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: It might help if you could debug/log the full path that you are writing to. Also, if you allow anonymous uploads, `current_user_id` will be `null` in that case.

Comment: Hi Peter, welcome to SO. Please proofread your questions and have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask